# How to identify IWebElement

Tags: .net, selenium, testing, frontend

If I have an element, defined by some selector off `By`, is there a good way to identify it to a (test) user?

For example:

```
var element = driver.Find(By.CssSelector(".some .css"));

throw new SomeCustomTestingException(element);
```

What would be good properties to use so that the test output allows the user to identify the element?

e.g.

```
"Error with element with Css = something"
"Error with element on page MyPage with XPath"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium's native logger. [LoggingPreferences](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingPreferences.html). It provides multiple level of logging and much more.
Those API are not avaiable in .NET yet unfortunately. Another option can be [log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: That would be useful... if they were implemented in .NET Selenium.

Comment: I was about to edit my post. Those api are not available in .net yet unfortunately. But, is that what you are looking for?. Probably similar options is [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: It might have been, but if I can figure out what properties on `IWebElement` they are using then I can hand roll a solution.

Comment: Most of the exceptions inherits [WebDriverException](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_WebDriverException.htm) and [Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c18k6c59) if that helps